# Cannot get sample CustomLoginModule to work

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I imported the project from the zip file on worklight getting started page. build android, run as android and got the error below when I click 'call protected adadpter proc'

> 07-03 09:21:29.400: E/NONE(822):
>   [http://'':10080/CustomLoginModule/apps/services/api/CustomLoginModule/android/query]
>   failure. state: 500, response: FWLSE0009W: User identity is null.
>   Check your application's authentication requirements. These settings
>   must match to the deployed application [project CustomLoginModule]

Comment: Try cleaning the project. In Eclipse > Project > Clean... Then redeploy the adapter and application using the Run As menus.

Comment: Good news. I've rewritten the above as an answer. Please mark as Answered when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get the project running by cleaning the Worklight project.

In Eclipse, click on the Project menubar option and choose `Clean...`.
Next, re-deploy the adapter and application using the Run As menus.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar error but the Clean did not work for me.   I had to remove the project from the server and then redeploy it in order to resolve the problem.